# How to make **kwargs optional

Tags: python, optional-parameters, keyword-argument

I have two classes that have a method with the same name, but this method uses different parameters. So I thought about using `**kwargs` (see example below). But one of the two methods does not require any parameter, so I get this error:

> TypeError: print_smt() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

because it is passing an empty dictionary to the function, I suppose.

How can I solve this problem? Am I forced to use an `if` statement to call the function with and without parameters, or there is a better way to solve the problem?

```
class Bar(object):
  def print_smt(self, text):
    print(text)

class Foo(object):
  def print_smt(self):
    print("Nothing")

def test(obj, **p2):
  obj.print_smt(p2)


bar = Bar()
test(bar, text='print this')

foo = Foo()
test(foo) # This one breaks!
```

Comment: This feels like a poor design choice to begin with; we might be able to give you a better solution to your problem if you elaborate on what your two classes are doing and why you feel the need to give them different methods with the same name. I suspect a default argument would help you but I can't say for sure from this thin example.

Comment: If you _want_ to do the pass-a-nonempty-dict thing, by the way, that's possible without two separate calls (though I'd argue that the two-calls approach is more readable and thus preferable): `obj.print_smt(*([p2] if p2 else []))`. Then again, if determining whether that were feasible that were your real question, there would be no need for kwargs anywhere in this discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call:

```
def test(obj, **p2):
  obj.print_smt(p2)
```

...you're passing a **dictionary** to `print_smt()`. Even if it's an empty dictionary, it's still a dictionary, and you can't pass a dictionary as an argument to something that takes no arguments.

---

If you want to pass through keyword arguments *as keyword arguments*, rather than as a single positional argument with a dictionary, then do so:

```
def test(obj, **p2):
  obj.print_smt(**p2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to **unpack the kwargs** before passing it to the print_smt function. This works:

```
def test(obj, **p2):
  obj.print_smt(**p2)
```